# RegularExpression - Positive Integer with 1 Decimal Point

Tags: c#, regex, data-annotations

I can't seem to get the syntax correct for a RegularExpression using C# to only allow positive numbers with up to 1 decimal point.

I have the following `DataAnnotation` for positive integers working:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[^\-][\d\.]*", ErrorMessage = "Positive integers only")]
```

Any tips?

Comment: How come `..` is a valid positive integer? Or `3.14`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `^\d+(\.\d)?$`.

Answer (score 2):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.\d)?$", ErrorMessage = "Positive integers only")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose `^(0|[1-9]\d*(\.\d)?)$`. That way you also rule out things like `0001`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `@"^\d+([.]\d?)?$"`
The "." is a special character and has to be escaped, otherwise the answer by SLaks is alright.